# req.body is undefined in post route of express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is my router

```
router.post('/', async(req, res) => {

const posts = await loadPostsCollection()

await posts.insertOne({
    text: req.body.text,
    createdAt: new Date()
})
res.status(201).send()
})
```

This is terminal error

> listeining on port 3090 .....  (node:7764)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'text' of undefined
>       at /Users/macbook/Desktop/node-project/server/routes/api/posts.js:19:24
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5) (node:7764)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
>   error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>   without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>   with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:7764) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: what does console.log(req.body) give? also it seems for your second err, you should use a  trycatch statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because your `req.body` will yield the value `undefined`.
So, when you try to do `req.body.text` you get an error as you are trying to access the `text` property on an `undefined` value.

The reason why you get `undefined` is because your express app isn't able to parse the request body.

For this, you need to install the `body-parser` middleware dependency,

`npm i body-parser`

And then add this middleware to your express app,

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Reference: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html

Here is an example app,

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    return res.send(`Hello ${req.body.name}!`)
})

app.listen(3000, () =>
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
)
```

Now if you invoke the above example app using curl,

```
curl -XPOST localhost:3000 -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"Ram"}'
```

You get back the response "Hello Ram!"

Comment: `body-parser` is deprecated use `express.json()` instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66525078/bodyparser-is-deprecated