# BodyParser is deprecated

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

[image]

As the image shown, BodyParser now is deprecated, how to correct the bodyParser syntax or statement to remove the line-through?

Comment: What version of `body-parser` and `nodejs` are you using?

Comment: I'm using 1.19.0 body-parser and 14.15.0 Node.js

Comment: Please don't send image, prefer code : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 217, accepted):

If you are using Express 4.16+ you don't have to import `body-parser` anymore. You can do it just like this:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json()) // To parse the incoming requests with JSON payloads
```

Comment: You are welcome!.
And to use JSON you can just go with:

app.use(express.json())

Answer (score 26):

## Don't use body-parser

body parsing has become builtin with `express` So, simply use

```
app.use(express.json()) //For JSON requests
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

from directly express

You can uninstall body-parser using `npm uninstall body-parser`

**Then you can simply get the POST content from `req.body`**

```
app.post("/yourpath", (req, res)=>{

    var postData = req.body;

    //Or like this, for string JSON body

    var postData = JSON.parse(req.body);
});
```

Comment: is `JSON.parse(req.body)` really needed as long as you used `app.use(express.json())` ? I tried to use JSON object properties without `JSON.parse()` and it still works.

Comment: @Sixteen Yes it works directly as long as the request has a JSON format and you won't need to use `JSON.parse()`. But for requests that send JSON in a string form, you will have to use `JSON.parse()` to get a usable JSON object. One example could be a frontend code that uses `fetch` to send request to server and sends object as string using `JSON.stringify()`

Answer (score 25):

Same issue occur to my projects also .
Now in latest express we don't need to import body-parse, we can just use express as follow.

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

or
if you limit size

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: "50mb", parameterLimit: 500000000 }));
```