# node - How to get POST request params and then redirect user in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, express, post

I had [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66525078/bodyparser-is-deprecated) while I was trying to setup a post endpoint for my nodejs cli script that is using express to manage requests

```js
        app.use( express.static( path.format({dir: __dirname, base: 'client/dist'})) );
        app.use( express.json() );

        app.get('/:uid', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.format({dir: __dirname, base: 'client/dist/index.html'})) );        

        app.listen(this.port, async () => {
            console.log(`Server started at: http://localhost:${this.port}`);
        });
```

I'm using express `4.17.1` so it's not needed to install `bodyParser`. How I will get the data posted from my vue front end, process them and then redirect user?

```js
app.post('/action', (req, res) => {   
  // how I can get the passed params here and redirect user?
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have it's pretty simple :

```
app.post('/action', (req, res) => {   
  // how I can get the passed params here and redirect user?
  console.log(req.body)// give you the passed parameter in post request thanks to app.use( express.json() );
  res.redirect('http://google.com');
});
```

Comment: If I want to access for examle to the param username in `req.body` object, I can simply do `req.body.username` right?

Comment: yup that's it !

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html you can see what method you have on request and response object here