# Express 4.17 body-Parser is deprecated

Tags: javascript, express

[JavaScript express server

```
app.use(express.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
```

Used this and it also didn't work][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dsEq.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66525078/bodyparser-is-deprecated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BodyParser is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66525078/bodyparser-is-deprecated)